# how to extract to, subject etc fron email in android emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I want to extract "To" and "Subject" from email clent which is already configured in android emulator.

so, is any api to extract or to get all email attributes?

Thanx in advance,

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry.

Bear in mind that there is no single email client in Android. The Android open source project has one, but device manufacturers can (and do) replace it. Plus there is Gmail and other third-party mail clients (e.g., K9). Hence, there is no single email client "which is already configured in android". And the open source one is not part of the SDK, so there is nothing in the API for accessing it.